# Secure Canvas - Should every http request on the canvas page also change to https?

Tags: security, canvas, configure, facebook-iframe

Since 1st Oct is coming. I am working on Secure Canvas URL stuff.

My canvas url is like **canvas.example.com**. I can make this domain and server SSL ready without a problem.

My question is, should every http request made by canvas.example.com also change to https?

***e.g.*** I import some JS, CSS, images from **cdn.example.com** to my canvas page, should i configure **cdn.example.com** alos can be accessed via https, or I can just leave this domain alone, still use http to get those content?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should make all content served over https or the browser will show warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook policies clearly mention that all the Page Tabs and iFrame Applications shal have an SSL certificate..
Any external content like images and JS included on your site shall also come from secured hostings hence the Https:// else your shall not be complying to FB Policies..
Gives the fact that FB has been very strict on punishing defaulters i dont think any app developer can take risk ..